# Accessing view without findViewByID?

Tags: android, kotlin, view

I am trying to set text for views in my recyclerview.

I'm following this example: https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/

I've added the plugins they suggest to the

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.email_list_item.view.tv_email_subject
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.email_list_item.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.email_list_item.tv_email_subject
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.email_list_item.*


class EmailAdapter(val emails: Observer<List<List<String>>>, val emailcontext: Context) :
    android.support.v7.recyclerview.extensions.ListAdapter<List<List<String>>,RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(ListItemCallback()) {
    //private val mOnClickListener:OnClickListener = OnClickListener()
    private val tvEmailSubject = tv_email_subject
    private val tvEmailFrom = view.tv_email_from
    private val tvEmailSynopsis = view.tv_email_synopsis
    private val tvEmailTags = view.tv_email_tags
```

The import statements recognize the views I'm trying to access, but inside my class, when I try to set `val tvEmailSubject = tv_email_subject`, it tells me "unresolved reference," even though it is explicitly imported.

How do I set text from my class this way?

Comment: Try the "Recovering views from another view" instructions from that blog post.

Comment: @CommonsWare That's what I've done. Unfortunately, it's not recognizing tv_email_subject, so I cannot access tv_email_subject.text. I've updated the question to include those imports

Comment: "That's what I've done" -- definitely not for `tv_email_subject`. There, you are using the syntax suitable for an activity or fragment, and `EmailAdapter` is neither of those. I don't really understand what the other lines are doing (where is `view` coming from? why would a `ListAdapter` be trying to access individual widgets from it?).

Answer (score 12):

Just apply this plugin in your **App module Gradle** file,

```
plugins {
    //...
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

Now access view element without having **findViewById()** method. Use the only View Id.

Comment: It's deprecated now.

Comment: Well, it seems that this plugin enables synthetic main or something.

Comment: It's deprecated, follow this guide instead https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration

Answer (score 1):

Add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` in top of build.gradle(:app) file

Answer (score 1):

### Without using `findViewByID` in fragments:

Enable `viewBinding = true` in `build.gradle (Module :app)`. i.e.

```
android{
...
buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

then define inside of fragment:
`private var binding: FragmentNameBinding? = null`

Then

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val fragmentBinding = FragmentNameBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding = fragmentBinding
        return fragmentBinding.root
    }
```

then use (inside of `onViewCreated`)

```
binding?.apply {
            var btn1 = btnpress1 //<---- xml id: btn_press_1
            btnpress2.text = "Hi!" //<---- xml id: btn_press_2
            mytextview.text = "I am a TextView" //<---- xml id: mytextview
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move this code into the view holder.  The adapter itself doesn't have a view, and it can't pull any of these view references.  They will not have been rendered at the time of the initialization of an adapter.

The example that you've shown in the url has it down in the OnCreate.  The view has been created and therefore these elements can be accessed.  An adapter works a bit different.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    welcomeMessage.text = "Hello Kotlin!"
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, I added `p0.tv_email_subject.text = "Hello Kotlin"` to my `onCreateViewHolder` and it works now. Initially I was trying to update these fields in `onBindViewHolder`. is that incorrect to do? The question now back to how do I get the data from the observer

Comment: I usually create a bind(object: Object) function in my view holder.  And then in the OnBind I call the viewHolders bind function and pass the object/data from the list to it.  And then I set the text or w/e properties inside that function.  That make sense?